# How to edit an address from the address book of the customer using the address id?

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, customer-address, address

I have to edit the address of the customer programmatically using the address id. Here I have customer id and address id of the address to be edited. I tried the following code. But it is not working.

```
$customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$customerAddress->load($data['address_id']);
$customerAddress->setCustomerId($data['customer_id']);
$customerAddress->setWebsiteId(1);
$customerAddress->setStore(1);      
$customerAddress->setFirstname('test');
$customerAddress->save();
```

It gives following error `Call to a member function getStore() on boolean in ../app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Observer.php`

I need to edit all fields of the address. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$customerAddress->load($data['address_id']);

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($data['customer_id']);
if($customer->getId()){ //if customer exist
  $customerAddress->setCustomer($customer);
  $customerAddress->setWebsiteId(1);
  $customerAddress->setStore(1);      
  $customerAddress->setFirstname('test');
  $customerAddress->save();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are setting an invalid customer id on customer address entity and hence you are getting this error. Please try below code, which is an alternative solution in this context.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($data['customer_id']);

//make sure customer exist
if (isset($customer->getId())) {
    $customerAddress = $customer->getAddressById($data['address_id']);

    //make sure address is really associated with the customer who is editing
    if (isset($customerAddress->getId())) {
        $customerAddress->setWebsiteId(1);
        $customerAddress->setStore(1);      
        $customerAddress->setFirstname('test');
        $customerAddress->save();
    } else {
        Mage::throwException('Address is not associated  with this customer !');
    }

} else {
    Mage::throwException('Customer is not valid customer !');
}
```

You can also go on with [**@Adarsh's Answer**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121753/3535) as it really checks customer exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code:-

```
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customerAddressId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling();
    $customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
    $customerAddress->load($customerAddressId);
    $customerAddress->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
    $customerAddress->setWebsiteId(1);
    $customerAddress->setStore(1);      
    $customerAddress->setFirstname('test');
    $customerAddress->save();
```